# Can I call Admob Request many times in Android project?

Tags: android, admob

My banner Ad is set automatically refesh. But, can I call Admob Request many times, just for 1 banner Ad in Android project? Is there any violation?

Answer (score 0):

You should set your banner ads up to refresh every 30-60 seconds.
I would recommend that you display them continuously throughout your app, don't show and hide them.